# Joining a mySQL table with a sum select

Tags: mysql, join, sum, left-join

I'm wondering if there's any way to combine these two queries:

```
SELECT posts.post_id, posts.member_id, posts.content, posts.date_created, votes.votes
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN votes
ON posts.post_id=votes.post_id
ORDER BY votes.votes;

SELECT post_id, SUM(votes) AS votes_total FROM votes GROUP BY post_id;
```

I tried to do it this way, but it just calculated the total amount of votes for all the posts, not each one:

```
SELECT posts.post_id, posts.member_id, posts.content, posts.date_created, SUM(votes) AS votes_total 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN votes
ON posts.post_id=votes.post_id
ORDER BY votes.votes;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT p.post_id, p.member_id, p.content, p.date_created, 
       SUM(v.votes) AS votes_total
FROM posts p LEFT JOIN
     votes v
     ON p.post_id = v.post_id
GROUP BY post_id
ORDER BY votes_total;
```

In general, you want all the columns in the `SELECT` that are not arguments to aggregation functions, to also be in the `GROUP BY`:

```
GROUP BY p.post_id, p.member_id, p.content, p.date_created
```

In this case, though, `post_id` is (presumably) the primary key in `posts`.  So, all the other columns would be superfluous in the aggregation.